# How to modify a text file using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this following text file:

> 1. It’s hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they always take things literally.
> 2. I used to think the brain was the most important organ. Then I thought, look what’s telling me that.

I use the following script to get rid of the numberings and newlines:

```
import re
with open('jokes.txt', 'r+') as original_file:
    modfile = original_file.read()
    modfile = re.sub("\d+\. ", "", modfile)
    modfile = re.sub("\n", "", modfile)
    original_file.seek(0)
    original_file.truncate()
    original_file.write(modfile)
```

After running the script, this how my text file is:

> It’s hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they always take
>   things literally. I used to think the brain was the most important
>   organ. Then I thought, look what’s telling me that.

I'd like the file to be:

> It’s hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they always take things literally.
>   I used to think the brain was the most important organ. Then I thought, look what’s telling me that.

How do I delete the new lines without mending all the lines?

Comment: why are you wanting to remove newlines?

Comment: I'm creating a twitter bot... It crashes when it jumps to an empty line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single replace, with the following regex:

```
re.sub(r"\d+\. |(?<!^)\n", "", modfile, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

`(?<!^)\n` will match a newline unless it's at the start of a line. The flag `re.MULTILINE` makes `^` match every beginning of line.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG3pX0)

In code:

```
import re
with open('jokes.txt', 'r+') as original_file:
    modfile = original_file.read()
    midfile = re.sub(r"\d+\. |(?<!^)\n", "", modfile, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    original_file.seek(0)
    original_file.truncate()
    original_file.write(modfile)
```

---

You can also use a negative lookahead instead of a lookbehind if you want:

```
r"\d+\. |\n(?!\n)"
```

Comment: It's still the same. The regex failed to substitute both the digits and the newline.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKC Strange, because it should work anyway, like [here](http://ideone.com/vXFwnw).

Comment: Is there any specific reason why it fails for me? I tried it again. Still it wont work with the raw string.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKC No sorry, I have no idea. It could be something specific to your system =/ Well, if raw strings don't work, just use the normal string I guess.